# In grails application message file content changed in UI

Tags: grails

In my grails application.
Place an messages_fr_FR.properties in UTF-8 format, but in UI it the message content is changed.

Examples:
Include French character `'àâäè'Çç` in message file.
But in UI it is displayed as `'Ã Ã¢Ã¤Ã¨'ÃÃ§`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem (on my first use of GGTS).

It was not a problem with Grails, but with the encoding of the text editor (MacRoman instead of UTF-8). You could also check the encoding of your webpage.